# Accordion with 60 basses chart

Tags: accordion

My grandfather gave me an accordion and it has 60 basses (5x12), which I find for a bit unusual.

I cannot find the chart for such accordion.
Anyone knows what kind of accordion is this and where I can find the basses chart?

Answer (score 4):

60 basses is bog standard for small accordions.  The central diagonal around the specially marked C bass has notes E-C-c-cm-c7 (upper case letters are single notes, here bass notes, lower case are chords).  c is C-E-G (inversion is determined by where the chord octave is), cm is C-E♭-G, c7 is what is actually called gdim on a six-row bass, namely E-G-B♭ (for most music using alternating basses you would not notice the difference to the six-row c7, namely C-E-B♭).

Going upwards is "adding sharps", C-G-D-A-E-B-F♯-C♯, going downwards is "adding flats", C-F-B♭-E♭-A♭-D♭.  It's not precicely defined which 12 notes are available in the central role (well, all of them when ignoring enharmonics, but an enharmonic switch requires a jump across 12 diagonals).

Comment: Be interested to hear if there's a pitch difference between Db and C#!

Comment: There's no difference. In accordions with more than 12 rows, the bass buttons repeat to make fingering easier, but they play the same notes.

Answer (score 3):

I know almost nothing about accordions, but I did find a fingering chart that includes 60 bass.

[image: source: pitorchestraexperience.wordpress.com]

There seem to be many models that have 60 bass keys so you need to give more information for that part of the question.

Comment: okay, but why the bigger part of the buttons are empty and do not show the chord?

Comment: you can extrapolate what goes in the circles because its a pattern

Comment: Another helpful way to identify your keyboard is by a search on "accordion key chart", then selecting the "more images" link. To specifically identify your instrument, go to https://www.accordionists.info/ and post a question. You will probably get more help than you need.

Answer (score 0):

The most detailed and complete 60 bass accordion chart/diagram I've found is this:
https://accordionchords.com/stradella-bass-layouts/60-bass-accordion-chart/

It shows all single notes played by each button and a list of all available and unavailable chords you can play.